# SpringBootTest hangs following Java 21 migration

Tags: spring-boot, migration, upgrade, spring-boot-test, java-21

Im trying to upgrage a SpringBoot 3.2.1/Java 17 application to Java 21. The app seems to be working fine but im facing an issue with all SpringBootTest tests. The test istself is successful but it seems to be stuck hanging after execution. I have extracted a thread dump and it looks like the snippet below.

Im thinking it may be related to `Jndi-Dns-address-change-listener` but im not sure and i haven't the faintest idea on how to solve this. Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help

```java
"Attach Listener@10326" tid=0xc nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Jndi-Dns-address-change-listener@19314" tid=0x57 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.net.dns.ResolverConfigurationImpl.notifyAddrChange0(ResolverConfigurationImpl.java:-1)
      at sun.net.dns.ResolverConfigurationImpl$AddressChangeListener.run(ResolverConfigurationImpl.java:179)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
      at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:186)

"Notification Thread@1328" tid=0x2a nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Reference Handler@26419" tid=0x9 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Reference.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:246)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:208)

"Signal Dispatcher@26421" tid=0xb nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"container-0@18025" tid=0x53 nid=NA sleeping
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep0(Thread.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:509)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:564)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer$1.run(TomcatWebServer.java:217)

"Catalina-utility-1@18010" tid=0x51 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:269)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1758)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"Catalina-utility-2@18018" tid=0x52 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:371)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:519)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3780)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3725)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1707)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"Common-Cleaner@26422" tid=0x1b nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:269)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1847)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.await(ReferenceQueue.java:71)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove0(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:218)
      at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(CleanerImpl.java:140)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
      at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:186)

"Finalizer@26420" tid=0xa nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait0(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.<obsolete>(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.<obsolete>(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.NativeReferenceQueue.await(NativeReferenceQueue.java:48)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove0(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
      at java.lang.ref.NativeReferenceQueue.remove(NativeReferenceQueue.java:89)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:173)

"HikariPool-1 housekeeper@12494" tid=0x4f nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:269)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1758)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"main@1" tid=0x1 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait0(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:366)
      at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:2078)
      at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:2154)
      at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:114)
      at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:47)
      at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:130)
      at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:167)
      - locked <0x5b0> (a java.lang.Class)
      at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:188)
      at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:1920)
      at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:56)

"OkHttp TaskRunner@25400" tid=0x9a nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait0(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:366)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:488)
      at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$RealBackend.coordinatorWait(TaskRunner.kt:294)
      at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.awaitTaskToRun(TaskRunner.kt:218)
      at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$runnable$1.run(TaskRunner.kt:59)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"pool-4-thread-1@18840" tid=0x56 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:269)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1758)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"pool-5-thread-1@25043" tid=0x98 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:371)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:519)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3780)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3725)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1707)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"pool-5-thread-2@25517" tid=0xa0 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:371)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:519)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3780)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3725)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1707)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"pool-5-thread-3@25746" tid=0xa1 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:371)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:519)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3780)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3725)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1707)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"pool-5-thread-4@25747" tid=0xa2 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:371)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:519)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3780)
      at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3725)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1707)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1070)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"PostgreSQL-JDBC-Cleaner@12465" tid=0x4e nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:269)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1847)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.await(ReferenceQueue.java:71)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove0(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:218)
      at org.postgresql.util.LazyCleaner$1.run(LazyCleaner.java:128)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"SpringApplicationShutdownHook@26510" tid=0x4a nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:269)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1758)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1475)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.awaitTermination(Executors.java:780)
      at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.close(ExecutorService.java:417)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:232)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1202)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1195)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1184)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1145)
      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:174)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1091)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.closeAndWait(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:145)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook$$Lambda/0x000001a7826aa2c8.accept(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.run(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:114)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

"testcontainers-ryuk@4563" tid=0x32 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait0(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:366)
      at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.lambda$null$1(RyukResourceReaper.java:115)
      at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper$$Lambda/0x000001a7812beef0.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at org.rnorth.ducttape.ratelimits.RateLimiter.doWhenReady(RateLimiter.java:27)
      at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.lambda$maybeStart$2(RyukResourceReaper.java:101)
      at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper$$Lambda/0x000001a7812becd0.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more information (code example, used Spring Boot version) about a sample test that hangs?